# aspnet core integration test returning 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to implement the integration test for my app following the tutorial from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing

```
public class CreditCardApplicationShould
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task RenderApplicationForm()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(@"C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\CreditCardApp\CreditCardApp")
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseStartup<CreditCardApp.Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights();

        var server = new TestServer(builder);

        var client = server.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync("/Apply/Index");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.Contains("New Credit Card Application", responseString);
    }
}
```

However, when I'm trying to run the integration test, it gives me the following error:

> "Message: System.InvalidOperationException : The view 'Index' was not
>   found. The following locations were searched:
>   /Views/Apply/Index.cshtml /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml"

It seems to be a common problem when separating the integration test from the MVC application.

Here's the startup.cs too

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        CurrentEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    private IHostingEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get;  }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(ApplyController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

I've found some work arounds, that says to include the AddApplicationPart in the Startup.cs, but it's still not working.

I'm not sure if it's not working because I'm using .NET Core 2.0. I appreciate any tips.

Comment: I think you need to verify the content root path

Comment: @Nkosi It's not working too. As you can see, I'm hard coding the path for ContentRoot and even with that, no success...

Comment: Take a look at how the path is being set here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844252/5233410

Comment: Definitely looks like a ContentRootPath issue to me.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem like you have and I solved it by adding `appsettings.json` file path to `WebHostBuilder()`. I implemented like following.

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(@"C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\CreditCardApp\CreditCardApp")
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseStartup<CreditCardApp.Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(YourProjectPath) // @"C:\Users\usuario\source\repos\CreditCardApp\CreditCardApp"
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build()
            );
```