# Using HttpConfiguration in ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I created an empty asp.net web application project with rc2. My project file is:

```
{
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10025",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to add `HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();` in my unit test.

But `HtppConfiguration` is from ASP.NET WEB API 2. How to change my project.json file? Or is there any replacement for it in ASP.NET CORE RC2?

Comment: Why do you need it? Why do you want to change it? What you're doing do not sound like unit test. Unit test should only test small chunks of code (units). You should redesign your classes instead, depending on a configuration file in unit test is definitely wrong

Comment: @Tseng, I want to do in memory unit test. See the [example here.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kiranchalla/2012/05/05/in-memory-client-host-and-integration-testing-of-your-web-api-service/) Is the example wrong?

Comment: If you'd have read the title of this article, you'd have realized it's not about unit testing ;)

Comment: @Tseng, my bad:). It is an integration test. But whatever, how to get `HtppConfiguration` in asp.net core rc2?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Use an alternate project.json? Or do you want to replace certain dependencies with mocks? You could check out how Swashbuckle Swagger (ASP.NET Core Swagger Generator) does integration tests here https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/blob/master/test/Swashbuckle.IntegrationTests/SwaggerGenIntegrationTests.cs#L42-L64. Basically it boils down to having separate projects with their own project.json

Comment: @Tseng, I wan to use an alternate project.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Core provides an easy way for integration testing using `TestServer` class. The following may help to start using it:

- an ASP.Net Core [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html) about integration testing.
- a [post](http://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-integration-testing-with-xunit-and-testserver-in-asp-net-core/) about using TestServer with [example](https://github.com/andrewlock/blog-examples/tree/master/xunit-integration) on github.
- a [TestServerTests.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/8f5f8d28d00468725d9fd8dd95123f43d22f2c3c/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.Tests/TestServerTests.cs) file from [Hosting](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting) repo, that contains xunit tests for TestServer. May help to review, what TestServer can do.
- good question on SO: ["Why the TestServer (AspNetCore) gives 404 error on static files?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815267/why-the-testserver-aspnetcore-gives-404-error-on-static-files)

and keep in mind that a lot of projects in https://github.com/aspnet use TestServer for testing (like [Diagnostics](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics) ).

Comment: It is hard to follow. I find the [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/1.0.0-rc1/aspnet/mvc/controllers/testing/sample/TestingControllersSample/src/TestingControllersSample). But there is no zip file or git to pull the sample.

Comment: I marked the answer, thanks. I have a following question, if I want to add a unit test or integration test project. What is the project template? Is it a unit test project or just a folder under the web application project? From asp.net team [document](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/unit-testing.html), the test project has a project.json file. My question is if it is an unit test project template, there is no project.json.

Comment: You should create a simple .NET Core Class Library Project (that by default, as any .NET Core project  will have project.json file), as unit tests is a classes with public methods.